# How to know the length of a char array belonging to a structure in runtime

Tags: c#, arrays

In the following code an exception is thrown.

> 'type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array
>   instance does not match the declared length in the layout'

I know it's because of the mismatch of the length of string and char array that I try to fix the length of string with blank characters.

To add blank characters I should know the length of the target char array in RUNTIME but I can't because the char array member is null yet.

How can I get the length of the char array? Is there any better way than mine?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct TestStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)] public char[] CharArray;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _TestStruct = new TestStruct();
    var _IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(_TestStruct));
    var _String = "a";

    _TestStruct.CharArray = _String.ToCharArray();
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(_TestStruct, _IntPtr, false); // ERROR

    // void TestFunction(IntPtr _Intptr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_IntPtr);
}
```

Comment: Well, you know it is 5.  Keep the String.PadRight() you need close to the declaration by adding a property to the struct.  Or use a `const` declaration.  Do keep in mind that native code normally would expect a string no longer than 4, terminated with a zero.  Which does mean that you should declare it string instead of char[], keep the [MarshalAs].

Comment: @HansPassant I appreciate your comment. I don't know the length in RUNTIME. In the actual code the members can be more than 50 and the structs 200~300 not same each other. I should randomly access the structs and the members in runtime.

Comment: Hmya, you are asking for a pony.  The usual caution applies, treat whomever is going to maintain your code some day like a homicidal maniac that knows where you live.  Never duplicate two hundred+ large struct declarations, keep the code unmanaged.  Look at C++/CLI and the SWIG tool.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry that english is not my mother tongue. I don't duplicate the same struct declaration. All are same kind but different.

Comment: Could the `SizeConst = 5` change, or is it always 5?

Comment: @AndersCarstensen It will be not changed but there will be other members which have various their own length. That's why I want the RUNTIME length. Thanks Anders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the 5 as a constant, you can pad up the char array with zeros to make it fill up the required size:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct TestStruct
{
    public const int CharArraySize = 5;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = CharArraySize)] public char[] CharArray;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestStruct _TestStruct = new TestStruct();

    IntPtr _IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(_TestStruct));

    string _String = "a";

    _TestStruct.CharArray = _String.ToCharArray();
    if (_TestStruct.CharArray.Length < TestStruct.CharArraySize)
        _TestStruct.CharArray = _TestStruct.CharArray.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((char)0, TestStruct.CharArraySize - _TestStruct.CharArray.Length)).ToArray();

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(_TestStruct, _IntPtr, false); // This works now

    // void TestFunction(IntPtr _Intptr);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_IntPtr);
}
```

You could automate this process using reflection:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct TestStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)] public char[] CharArray;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)] public char[] CharArray2;
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestStruct _TestStruct = new TestStruct();

    IntPtr _IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(_TestStruct));

    _TestStruct.CharArray = "abcd".ToCharArray();
    _TestStruct.CharArray2 = "ab".ToCharArray();
    _TestStruct = (TestStruct)FixArraySizes(_TestStruct); // Due to TestStruct being a struct, we must unbox the result.

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(_TestStruct, _IntPtr, false);

    // void TestFunction(IntPtr _Intptr);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_IntPtr);
}

private object FixArraySizes(object obj) {
    var objType = obj.GetType();
    var fieldInfos = objType.FindMembers(MemberTypes.Field, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, (info, _) => ((FieldInfo)info).FieldType == typeof(char[]), null);
    foreach (FieldInfo info in fieldInfos) {
        var fieldValue = (char[])info.GetValue(obj);
        var sizeOfArray = (int?)info.GetCustomAttributesData().FirstOrDefault(attr => attr.AttributeType == typeof(MarshalAsAttribute))?.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault(arg => arg.MemberName == "SizeConst").TypedValue.Value;
        if (sizeOfArray.HasValue)
        {
            fieldValue = FixArraySize(fieldValue, sizeOfArray.Value);
            info.SetValue(obj, fieldValue);
        }
    }

    return obj;
}

private char[] FixArraySize(char[] array, int expectedSize)
{
    if (array.Length < expectedSize)
        array = array.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((char)0, expectedSize - array.Length)).ToArray();
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I said actually there are many struct memebers. Following your suggestion I have to declare as many as array size varialbles and call them one by one. Isn't there any simpler way to assign a value to a char array in a struct?

Comment: I added another solution which is based on string instead of char array. (It is still marshalled into an array of chars.)

Comment: I appreciate again your solution. But using string replaces the last character to null that the last character and the value of following members are ingnored when they are passed by the function. I think I should use a char array.

Comment: I am not aware of a simple way of doing it. But you can write your own method for doing it... I have updated my second solution; now it will automatically change update all char arrays in the struct to pad them with zeroes. All you need to do is call `_TestStruct = (TestStruct)FixArraySizes(_TestStruct);` before `Marshal.StructureToPtr`.